# Separate 2 video streams from one MPEG-2 file into 2 files

Tags: matlab, video, mpeg-2

I'm really rookie in manipulating with video files and I have question.

I have one MPEG-2 file with two video streams synchronized by time (first from RGB camera and second from thermal camera). I would like to separate this streams into two files (to any format). Is it possible ? Can I use MATLAB or another software ?

Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at `ffmpeg`?

Comment: What happens when you play the video file using a normal video player? Are the frames interleaved?  If that's the case, you can load the file in MATLAB as you wish, then simply pick out the odd and even frames.

Comment: @Shai Not yet deeply, but on first view it has many parameters. Thanks for idea.

Comment: @rayryeng If I play file in VLC player, he opens two separate windows, where the 'main' window is with RGB video. I can control playback of both windows together from main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg` will do the job ! It might look like a kludge because it has indeed a lot of options but it is very powerful for video stream manipulation.

Have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/743646/ffmpeg-h264-split-demux-a-stream-video).